# Alert on select option change

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code that shows an `alert();` on option change

How can I stop it showing the alert on one of the options but keep it on all others?

```
<select onchange="alert();">
    <option>d</option>
    <option>de</option>
    <option>dewe</option>
    <option>dewee</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I believe you will have to test the value in your handler

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness not really a helpful comment was it?

Comment: If you can change the html and don't need it there for anything else, it is usually the proper thing to do...

Comment: @user2710234: Using data attributes you can create a quite generic solution without having to interrogate the actual option text/value itself. I added examples of that in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simple make a handler and can put the condition like this

```
function alertMessage()
{
    if(document.getElementById('select').value !="d"){
        alert('yes');
    }
}
```

your markup would be

```
<select id="select" onchange="alertMessage();">
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9L4X/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the example when you don't want option **d** to raise alert:

```
 <select onchange="if(this.value!='d'){alert('yes');}">
                <option>d</option>
                <option>de</option>
                <option>dewe</option>
                <option>dewee</option>
            </select>
```

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5B32V/) onchange event is modified to call custom function when event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

For example you don't need alert for second option `de`:

```
<select onchange="selectChangeHandler(this)">
    <option>d</option>
    <option>de</option>
    <option>dewe</option>
    <option>dewee</option>
</select>
<script>
    function selectChangeHandler(selectNode) {
         if (selectNode.selectedIndex !== 1) {
             alert("I'm alert option!");
         }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("select").change(function()
{
if($(this).val() != "dee")
alert($(this).val());
});
});
</script> 
</head>


<select>
<option>d</option>
<option>de</option>
<option>dee</option>
<option>deep</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a more generic  solution you could add a data attribute to the options you are interested in, update your `onchange` to call a custom function, passing it the event data, similar to this:

```
<select onchange="doSelectAlert(event);">
    <option data-no-alert>d</option>
    <option>de</option>
    <option>dewe</option>
    <option>dewee</option>
</select>
```

You can then interrogate the event data to only alert the options which have a specific attribute, similar to this:

```
function doSelectAlert(event) {
    var option = event.srcElement.children[event.srcElement.selectedIndex];
    if(option.dataset.alert !== undefined){
        alert('Hello Selection');
    }
}
```

Off course, if you have more options to be alerted than not you can inverse the logic and add a data attribute like `data-no-alert` and change the code to alert all but the options which have that attribute, similar to this:

```
<select onchange="doSelectAlert(event);">
    <option data-no-alert>d</option>
    <option>de</option>
    <option>dewe</option>
    <option>dewee</option>
</select>
```

```
function doSelectAlert(event) {
    var option = event.srcElement.children[event.srcElement.selectedIndex];
    if (option.dataset.noAlert !== undefined) {
        return;
    }

    alert('Hello Selection');
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VU6h6/) - Marking specific options for alert

---

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yqbA/) - Marking specific options to not alert

---

Note for IE 10 and lower support:

If you need to support IE 10 or below, change the `dataset` query to use plain old attribute 
syntax instead, similar to this:

```
function doSelectAlert(event) {
    var option = event.srcElement.children[event.srcElement.selectedIndex];

    // element.dataset is not supported in IE 10 or below
    // use standard attribute syntax instead...
    if (option.getAttribute('data-no-alert') !== null) {
        return;
    }

    alert('Hello Selection');
}
```

Or use [**modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/) to polyfill dataset use if you want to be able to use dataset.